# Make sense of a list in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm running into a little bit of a snag and I can't seem to research my way out of this, so I'm hoping for some pointers.

I'm using an 3x MCP23017 chips and putting them to output so that I can control a few things. I'm using the Adafruit MCP23017 library on Github, and this works well with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import board
import busio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from digitalio import Direction
from adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017 import MCP23017

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp1 = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x20)
mcp2 = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x24)
mcp3 = MCP23017(i2c, address=0x22)

#mcp1
one_port_pins = []
for pin in range(0, 15):
   one_port_pins.append(mcp3.get_pin(pin))

for pin in one_port_pins:
    pin.direction = Direction.OUTPUT

#mcp2
two_port_pins = []
for pin in range(0, 15):
   two_port_pins.append(mcp2.get_pin(pin))

for pin in two_port_pins:
    pin.direction = Direction.OUTPUT

#mcp3
three_port_pins = []
for pin in range(0, 15):
   three_port_pins.append(mcp3.get_pin(pin))

for pin in three_port_pins:
    pin.direction = Direction.OUTPUT
```

According to the example, I'm able to trigger them as such:

```
for pin in two_port_pins:
    pin.value = True
    time.sleep(0.2)
    pin.value = False
    time.sleep(0.2)
```

And this does trigger them and work great, however, at this stage, I would like to incorporate some of my other script, that would parse through some of the pin's need to be activated, although, I'm not quite sure how to match them.

Trying to print the lists one_port_pins, two_port_pins and three_port_pins gives me all sorts of data I'm not at all formiliar with when I try to print:

```
print(pin.__dict__)
>>> {'_pin': 0, '_mcp': <adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017.MCP23017 object at 0xb65d5230>}
>>> {'_pin': 1, '_mcp': <adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017.MCP23017 object at 0xb65d5230>}
>>> {'_pin': 2, '_mcp': <adafruit_mcp230xx.mcp23017.MCP23017 object at 0xb65d5230>}
```

Can someone tell me what I am looking at? How am I able to select a specific pin to activate?

Thank you!

Comment: A good starting point would be the source on git. https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MCP230xx/blob/main/adafruit_mcp230xx/mcp23017.py shows you that `MCP23017().get_pin()` returns an object of the `DigitalInOut` class which you can call a number of methods on. https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_MCP230xx/blob/63c459d3a8022d99b28ff83ffd45bbf39c537d05/adafruit_mcp230xx/digital_inout.py#L33

Comment: Or are you asking how to access objects from the `list`? `two_port_pins[0]`, `two_port_pins[1]`, etc..